# Compare Non Key Fields and detect update record

Tags: java

I have to prepare a logic where in a table there are two types of columns for a record.

- One that identifies a unique record means key fields
- that are non key fields

If key fields are changing then I have to update a record with Delete/Add operator. Whereas if non key fields are updating I have to use Change operator.

I get the records in List of object which using comparator  I am able to detect change in Key Fields and use Add/Delete operator.

Comparator logic is compare old Key fields in && with new key fields if there is a change Delete Operator for Old record and Add for new record added. This is straight.

But for Change operator what will be the best way to know which field is updated? Accordingly 'Change' will be added. Using comparator I can validate if something is changed or not, but what changed how to know using comparator or other thing?

As a example in below record ID, Open Date and Status are Key fields where as rest are non key fields

> ID, Open Date, Closed Date, Status, Est Closed Date

I can compare complete record for Non key comparision to know if something changed but what is changed I can't know because I have to update the same existing record with Update operator instead of Delete/Add.

I will run Add/Delete comparator check first and then will validate for non key fields changes. Please guide

**Update:** I think I answered my own question, first I will do Key Field comparision for a record to generate Add/Delete records on basis of updates in key fields combination and then  for same record i will do complete key comparision  if change is detected update operator will be added and no Insert/Delete will be generated. I don't need to detect which exact non key field changed.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to detect changes in the objects, or are you storing duplicates and using the comparator to compare them? Also, can you include some of your code

Comment: I am trying to compare and detect if any change in previous record vs new record. I think I get the answer. Thanks for considering and reading through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I answered my own question, first I will do Key Field comparison for a record and for same record i will do complete key comparison if change is detected update operator will be added and no Insert/Delete will be generated. I don't need to detect which exact non key field changed.

Thanks for looking my question and your time.